# IF statements program

Tags: if-statement, nested, expression, qbasic

I'm having an issue. I have to write a program for my calculator but I'm not sure how to do it. It uses a form of QBASIC language.

My statement is:

```
IF (y>0 and x>0) then it should calculate n:=ATAN(y/x);
IF (y<0 and x<0) then it should calculate n:=ATAN(y/x)+180;
IF (y>0 and x<0) then it should calculate n:=ATAN(y/x)+180;
IF (y<0 and x>0) then it should calculate n:=ATAN(y/x)+360;
```

I think I could only use (IF, ELSE, THEN)

Comment: "Here is my assignment, please implement it for me" is not generally allowed / on-topic here; questions are expected to include enough of your own work to show a specific problem you encountered _while trying to write the program yourself_.

Answer (score 0):

your code is

```
 cls
input x 
input y
if y>0 and x>0 then 
n=ATAN(y/x) 
else if y<0 and x<0 then 
n= ATAN(y/x)+ 180 
else if y>0 and x<0 then 
n=ATAN(y/x)+180 
else if y<0 and x>0 then 
n= ATAN(y/x)+360
endif
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `IF`, `THEN`, and `ELSE` are all you have then the following applies:

> The rule for a statement containing several `IF`s and `ELSE`s is that the first `ELSE` is associated with the closest preceding `IF`, and each subsequent `ELSE` with the closest unassigned preceding `IF`.

```
                                         first ELSE            subsequent ELSE                   first ELSE
                                         |                     |                                 |
                                         v                     v                                 v
IF y<0 THEN IF x<0 THEN n:=ATAN(y/x)+180 ELSE n:=ATAN(y/x)+360 ELSE IF x<0 THEN n:=ATAN(y/x)+180 ELSE n:=ATAN(y/x)
^           ^                            |                     |    ^                            |
|           \--- closest preceding IF ---/                     |    \--- closest preceding IF ---/
\---unassigned closest preceding IF ---------------------------/
```

If possible, use the somewhat less complex:

```
n:=ATAN(y/x): IF y<0 THEN IF x<0 THEN n:=n+180 ELSE n:=n+360 ELSE IF x<0 THEN n:=n+180
```

Comment: What your solution omits is the case where either x or y equals zero.  The OP never replied, though, so it's hardly worth even answering.